Weather patterns and national borders
I've been observing weather patterns, especially rain, and to me it looks like there is a correlation with national borders.
Of course it is nonsense to think rain clouds stop at national borders to avoid the toll collectors.
But perhaps thinking of it the other way, that national borders tend to be aligned with geological structures that also affect weather patterns.
Any thoughts? Is there any research into that?

Certainly many national borders are aligned with hills or mountain ranges which one might expect to affect weather. It's not beyond reason to think that some ethnically defined borders might have been influenced by a distinction between settled agriculturalists and pastoralists which, in turn may have a climate component.

Certain national borders are lined with mountains, seas, and other geological barriers that do make differences in the climate of the border lands. However, for much of the length of country borders, land forms and climate are the same on both sides of the boundary. Weather doesn't change much on the sides of national borders because such borders, and the nation-state itself, are completely arbitrary.

Your answer is surely true for North American borders, and much of post-colonial Africa.
